Area of shaded part of figure integral
Find the area of the shaded figure, integral.

Integral:
$$\int_{a}^{b} (4-x^2) \, dx$$
The limitation I am able to find from the figure,$\left[-4, 4\right]$.
Integrating:
$\int_{-4}^{4} (4-x^2) \, dx$
$\int_{-4}^{4} = \left[4x - \frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{-4}^{4}$
Applying:
$F(4)-F(-4) = -\frac{16}{3} - \frac{16}{3}$
$=-\frac{32}{3}$
My answer was wrong, according to the back of the book the correct solution is: $\frac{32}{3}$, mine is negative.

The integral limit is $[-2,2]$.

Your bounds are wrong, the parabola intercepts the x-axis at $(-2,0)$ and $(2,0)$. If you change your bounds of the integral to $$\int_{-2}^{2} (4-x^2) \, dx$$ then you should get the right answer.

How can you seem that?

@SaraJönsson since the green area seems to be represented as the area in between the curve and the x-axis, the left and right hand bounds of our integral must be the $x$ coordinates of those two points. We can solve for these two points by plugging in $y=0$ to $y=4-x^2$ to get $x^2 = 4$ and hence $x=-2,2$.

Omg! I totally forgot about this.
